# RMD Plots inside For Loop

Tags: r

I'm not understanding something fundamental in using pivot_longer. Let me share my results. Here a table. the temperature metrics are all doubles.

```
device_id   < 12°C  < 16°C  < 18°C  < 21°C  > 21°C
412222  0   0.355   0.645   0.000   0.000
C000037 0   0.000   0.048   0.539   0.412
P000000 0   0.000   0.105   0.620   0.275
W000043 0   0.000   0.057   0.562   0.380
W000069 0   0.359   0.641   0.000   0.000
W000075 0   0.000   0.036   0.521   0.443
```

And the outut from dput() which hopefully will allow you to rebuild.

```
structure(list(device_id = c("412222", "C000037", "P000000", 
"W000043", "W000069", "W000075"), `< 12°C` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), `< 16°C` = c(0.355, 0, 0, 0, 0.359, 0), `< 18°C` = c(0.645, 
0.048, 0.105, 0.057, 0.641, 0.036), `< 21°C` = c(0, 0.539, 0.62, 
0.562, 0, 0.521), `> 21°C` = c(0, 0.412, 0.275, 0.38, 0, 0.443
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

The following code does not do what I expect:

```
temp <- 
  risk_by_device %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols = c(select(., contains("°C")), na.rm = TRUE),
    names_to = "Score",
    values_to = "percentage"
)


Error in `as_indices_impl()`:
! Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript has the wrong type `tbl_df<
  < 12°C: double
  < 16°C: double
  < 18°C: double
  < 21°C: double
  > 21°C: double
>`.
i It must be numeric or character.
Backtrace:
  1. risk_by_device %>% ...
 23. rlang::cnd_signal(x)
 Error in as_indices_impl(x, vars, call = call, strict = strict) :
```

I have run very similar code on a daa set with strings and that work. It's not that pivot_longer doesn't work on doubles, is it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the helpfile of tidyr argument `cols` takes " Columns to pivot into longer format."
So the 4. row in your code is simply

```
cols = contains("°C"),
```

and you get your data in long format.
Since you want to pivot all the columns except the id-col you could also specify

```
cols = -device_id,
```

or even shorter

```
cols = -1,
```